# SSD and PPC with Leopard 10.5.8

Tags: ssd, leopard, trim

G5 quad core PPC with an SSD in it.  Should I continue looking for 'trim enabling' software?  It doesn't seem to exist.  Does the PPC architecture have a built in feature that manages SSD space?

Comment: What brand SSD are you using? [Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/downloads.html) keeps a relatively complete list of drivers/optimization software for their drives only, though some of it requires you boot from a CD using FreeDOS.

Comment: 120GB intell ssdsc2cw120a3  serial ATA, better boot times and better response with Photoshop CS3

Comment: I'm with you all the way there. Samsung 850 EVO in my old Lenovo T61 with XP Pro x64 and it actually runs MATLAB quicker than my early '11 MBP.

Answer (score 1):

You can look here[1]. The members of this thread seem to agree that writing 1s (FF) to unused space by the OS allows the GC on the disk to do its job, effectively the same as TRIM.

Unfortunately they devolve into insulting each others' knowledge of SSDs and Mac chipsets in general before doing anything useful. One of the commenters claimed there was a utility to write FF to unused blocks for PPC macs, but I've been unable to find it.

```
[1]: [http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1953430]
```

Comment: I would like to apologize for the wonky formatting, post preview on my iPhone is unavailable. Anyone wishing to fix this is surely welcome.

Comment: Jeez, this reminds me of Amiga people (of which I am admittedly one).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way a PPC can have any clue what an SSD is, nor any OS or driver that runs on it - they are 10 years apart in architectural terms.

I'd be happy enough it recognises the drive at all.

I do have to ask, how did you achieve it? SATA to PATA or is it a PCIe card?

Comment: G5 is already SATA.

Comment: Ah, so it it - I misread on Everymac.

Comment: No problem! I have G4, G5, MacPro, and went thru the migration, G4 to G5 still used PPC, but I had to make the jump to SATA, and move data off quite a few PATA hard drives. The move to MacPro let me keep drives but start to lose software that didn't like the move even under Rosetta.